# Having problem with encoding on input and output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, character-encoding

So I am reading a dataframe that contains a different language text, using the `read_excel(file, encoding='utf-8')` function in pandas, as I am being provided an Excel file.

What is coming in through Excel looking like this:

> Avez-vous, personnellement ou avec une autre personne, emprunté de
>   l'argent de n'importe quelle source, pour une raison quelconque, au
>   cours des 12 DERNIERS MOIS?

is being outputted using `to_csv(name, encoding='utf-8')` like this:

> Avez-vous, personnellement ou avec une autre personne, empruntÃ© de
>   l'argent de n'importe quelle source, pour une raison quelconque, au
>   cours des 12 DERNIERS MOIS?

Where am I going wrong with character encoding? How do I ensure that it stays in the original format? Is it because the CSV is treated like a text file? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide a sample Excel file and a snippet of code to reproduce the problem

Comment: It looks like you are reading the correct bytes incorrectly. I don't think you have a problem except in your test methodology. (Yes, a CSV file is a type of text file. There is no text but encoded text. Any program that reads text must use the character encoding that the writer used. In many cases, you must tell it.)